# Padding column values?

Tags: r, assign, indices, pad

In R 2.14.2 I have a matrix:

```
mat1=matrix(c('A','','','B'))
```

and I want to fill in the empty values so it becomes like this:

```
mat2=matrix(c('A','','','B','A','A','A','B'),2,4,byrow=T)
```

In other words, how do I pad the empty values?

[In Excel I would use this formula in column B: B2=if(isblank(A2),B1,A2), and copy it down].

How can I do this in R?

Henk

Comment: why not use something like this **mat1[nchar(mat1) == 0] <- 'A'** (you can replace 'A' with a vector like the B1 column in your Excel example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `na.locf` in package `zoo`. The `locf` means `last observation carried forward`, which is exactly what you are doing:

```
library(zoo)

x <- c('A',NA,NA,'B')
na.locf(x)

[1] "A" "A" "A" "B"
```

---

But make sure you understand the difference between `NA` and `""` (an empty string). In Excel it may be useful to use empty strings to prevent display of formulae, but in R it's much better to use `NA` to indicate missing values.

Comment: [SOLVED] thanks a lot! 
i had both n/a and blanks, and now realized that i could use: mat=csv.read('myfile.csv',na.strings=c('n/a',''). in other words, you can set more values to be picked up as NA.